# Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.dll not found

Tags: 2010

Why on SharePoint 2010 is there no Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.dll.
I can't find it anywhere.

Can I download Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.dll somewhere?

Please somebody help me.

Comment: Are you using sharepoint foundation or enterprise?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you need this dll, may be for code.

but you can obtain the Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.dll file from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC).

To do this, follow these steps:

- At a command prompt, locate the following folder:
  drive:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c>

**Note** The drive placeholder is the drive where your Windows operating system is installed on the server.

- Copy the Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.dll file to the required
  location, and then reference it.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982263

Comment: i can't seem to find it in that folder there's only Microsoft.office.securestoreservice.server.security dll

Comment: can you go this location \Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\ and if their is any folder for securestore service? why you need this?